# nginx if directive changes url in proxy_pass

Tags: if-statement, nginx, proxy, url-rewriting, proxypass

I am trying to use nginx to proxy to a secure download by setting an auth token as a cookie and then proxying with an additional header (`<a href="">` doesn't let me set headers).  I have found that the `if` directive is rewriting the url.

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "X-Auth-Token=(.+?)($|;)") {
}
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555/static;
```

When sending a `GET` request with `/private/foo.ext` it gets proxied to:  `/static/private/foo.ext`.

If I comment out the `if` directive:

```
# if ($http_cookie ~* "X-Auth-Token=(.+?)($|;)") {
# }
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555/static;
```

When sending a `GET` request with `/private/foo.ext` it gets proxied to:  `/static/foo.ext`.

The full code looks like this:

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "X-Auth-Token=(.+?)($|;)") {
    set $auth_token $1;
}
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555/static;
proxy_set_header X-Auth-Token $auth_token;
proxy_pass_request_header on;
```

But I commented out everything except the `if` directive and that seems to be what is changing the url.

Why is it adding `/private` in the url in one case and not the other?  I want it to remove `/private` from the path.

Edit: nginx version is 1.6.0.

Comment: `If` is evil. Use `map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the above suggestion, I abandoned using `if` in favor of `map`.  Here is the final result that is now working.

```
map $http_cookie $auth_token {
    "~.*?X-Auth-Token=(?<token>.*)(;|$)" $token;
}

location /private {
    proxy_set_header X-Auth-Token $auth_token;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555/static;
}
```

Comment: Probably you just need to use `$cookie_x_auth_token` variable without map.

Comment: Doesn't seem like I the $cookie_name syntax supports dashes in the variable name.  It doesn't recognize X-Auth-Token and x_auth_token as the same.